# How can I animate a storyboard instantly from a new value back to the original value before the animation was applied?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

In short, I know how to animate *from* a current value to a new value, but what I don't know how to do (and can't find) is how to animate back to the value before the animation ran.

In other words, say my current background is yellow.  I want to flash the background as red based on some logic, but I want it to fade from that red back to yellow again.   Transparent doesn't work here because it replaces the background value with 'Transparent', not fades through it.

Also, I'm not referring to the FillBehavior property which you can use to 'un-apply' the animated value after it's ran, nor am I referring to auto-reversing the animation as that would mean it would have to run forward first meaning we'd get a fade to the red, not an instant pulse as we want.

Only way I've found so far is to do this in code-behind, but that introduces its own issues with logically arranging things.  I just want the 'To' value to be set to the pre-animated value.  How can that be done?

Comment: And what's wrong with code behind? As long as it is view-related it's perfectly fine.

Comment: The problem with code-behind is that most of the other trigger-related things are defined in XAML, and therefore now you have to split the logic, let alone (re)structure your code to use resources that you can access from the code-behind.  Sure it works, but it's not optimal.

Comment: Maybe you could put something red above this yellow background and then animate it's from opacity 1 to 0 on trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ColorAnimation.From Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation.from.aspx) only as in this sample:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                From="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="AAA" Background="Yellow" />
    <TextBox Text="BBB" Background="Blue" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: MAN, that was easy!  Sheesh!  Embarrassed I didn't try that!